# How can you define the uint_fast32_t for MPI data types?

Tags: c, int, mpi

How can you define the MPI integer data type with the C/C++ `uint_fast32_t` or any other integer bit that uses the `fast` feature.

Comment: You don't define them because the `*fast*` integers may no map to an MPI type.  Types such as `uint_fast32_t` are provided as-is by whatever implementation of the C language you are using.  You need to use basic types as MPI requires.

Comment: As far as I understand `unit_fast32_t` is: depending on the architecture it may use an integer with more bits than 32 - something the compiler will take care off. Hence, how do I let MPI follow the same trend. From my understanding I only know that this integer is AT LEAST 32 bits, however, it could be more. This will likely lead to problems with MPI, if I had hardcoded the integer type for the MPI, no?

Comment: If, for example, `uint_fast32_t` is implemented by a platform as a 64-bit `unsigned long`, you gain nothing by adding in the extra layer to wind up using an `MPI::UNSIGNED_LONG` anyway.  The MPI types map to basic C/C++ types such as `int`, not the `*fast*` types.

Comment: In other words, IMO it's counterproductive to add an extra layer to try to get faster in a platform-specific way.  Just pick the fastest native `int`/`long`/`unsigned` for that platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume we work with an MPI implementation conforming to [MPI standard](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/) version 2.2 or later.

MPI 2.2 and later define signed integer datatypes `MPI_INT8_T`, `MPI_INT16_T`, `MPI_INT32_T`, `MPI_INT64_T` (corresponding to C `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, and `int64_t`), and unsigned integer datatypes `MPI_UINT8_T`, `MPI_UINT16_T`, `MPI_UINT32_T`, and `MPI_UINT64_T` (corresponding to C `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, and `uint64_t`).

This means that you can use these specific-size integer types directly in MPI in C.

---

The situation with minimum-width (`int_leastN_t`, `uint_leastN_t`) and fastest minimum-width (`int_fastN_t`, `uint_fastN_t`) integer types is different.  A [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) will tell you that you cannot really use these types with MPI, because the C or MPI standards do not provide a clean way to use them.

In practice, the situation is much simpler.  All existing C implementations supporting `<stdint.h>` types typedef the minimum-width and fastest minimum-width integer types to types compatible with the exact-width types.

Personally, I would create a header file, say `extra-mpi-types.h`, that includes the appropriate header file, say

```
/* extra_mpi_types.h */
#ifndef   EXTRA_MPI_TYPES_H

/* Use build-time generated file */
#include <extra_mpi_types_internal.h>

#endif /* EXTRA_MPI_TYPES_H */
```

where `extra_mpi_types_internal.h` is generated at build time by compiling and running something like

```
/* type_generator.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static inline const char *mpi_type_name(const char *const name, const size_t size, const int is_signed)
{
    if (is_signed) {
        if (size == sizeof (int8_t))  return "MPI_INT8_T";
        if (size == sizeof (int16_t)) return "MPI_INT16_T";
        if (size == sizeof (int32_t)) return "MPI_INT32_T";
        if (size == sizeof (int64_t)) return "MPI_INT64_T";
    } else {
        if (size == sizeof (uint8_t))  return "MPI_UINT8_T";
        if (size == sizeof (uint16_t)) return "MPI_UINT16_T";
        if (size == sizeof (uint32_t)) return "MPI_UINT32_T";
        if (size == sizeof (uint64_t)) return "MPI_UINT64_T";
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: Unsupported %s integer type.\n", name, (is_signed) ? "signed" : "unsigned");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static void define(const char *const mpiname, const char *const typename, const size_t typesize, const int is_signed)
{
    printf("#ifndef  %s\n", mpiname);
    printf("# define %s  %s\n", mpiname, mpi_type_name(typename, typesize, is_signed));
    printf("#endif\n");
}

#define  DEFINE_SIGNED(mpitype, type)    define(#mpitype, #type, sizeof (type), 1)
#define  DEFINE_UNSIGNED(mpitype, type)  define(#mpitype, #type, sizeof (type), 0)

int main(void)
{
    printf("/* This is an autogenerated header file: do not modify. */\n\n");

    DEFINE_SIGNED(MPI_INT_LEAST8_T,  int_least8_t);
    DEFINE_SIGNED(MPI_INT_LEAST16_T, int_least16_t);
    DEFINE_SIGNED(MPI_INT_LEAST32_T, int_least32_t);
    DEFINE_SIGNED(MPI_INT_LEAST64_T, int_least64_t);

    DEFINE_UNSIGNED(MPI_UINT_LEAST8_T,  uint_least8_t);
    DEFINE_UNSIGNED(MPI_UINT_LEAST16_T, uint_least16_t);
    DEFINE_UNSIGNED(MPI_UINT_LEAST32_T, uint_least32_t);
    DEFINE_UNSIGNED(MPI_UINT_LEAST64_T, uint_least64_t);

    DEFINE_SIGNED(MPI_INT_FAST8_T,  int_fast8_t);
    DEFINE_SIGNED(MPI_INT_FAST16_T, int_fast16_t);
    DEFINE_SIGNED(MPI_INT_FAST32_T, int_fast32_t);
    DEFINE_SIGNED(MPI_INT_FAST64_T, int_fast64_t);

    DEFINE_UNSIGNED(MPI_UINT_FAST8_T,  uint_fast8_t);
    DEFINE_UNSIGNED(MPI_UINT_FAST16_T, uint_fast16_t);
    DEFINE_UNSIGNED(MPI_UINT_FAST32_T, uint_fast32_t);
    DEFINE_UNSIGNED(MPI_UINT_FAST64_T, uint_fast64_t);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

redirecting its output to `extra_mpi_types_internal.h`.  Note that this depends only on the C implementation, and not on the MPI implementation at all.  This only finds out which fixed-width integer types match the minimum-width or minimum-width fast integer types.

On x86-64 Linux, this will generate

```
/* This is an autogenerated header file: do not modify. */

#ifndef  MPI_INT_LEAST8_T
# define MPI_INT_LEAST8_T  MPI_INT8_T
#endif
#ifndef  MPI_INT_LEAST16_T
# define MPI_INT_LEAST16_T  MPI_INT16_T
#endif
#ifndef  MPI_INT_LEAST32_T
# define MPI_INT_LEAST32_T  MPI_INT32_T
#endif
#ifndef  MPI_INT_LEAST64_T
# define MPI_INT_LEAST64_T  MPI_INT64_T
#endif
#ifndef  MPI_UINT_LEAST8_T
# define MPI_UINT_LEAST8_T  MPI_UINT8_T
#endif
#ifndef  MPI_UINT_LEAST16_T
# define MPI_UINT_LEAST16_T  MPI_UINT16_T
#endif
#ifndef  MPI_UINT_LEAST32_T
# define MPI_UINT_LEAST32_T  MPI_UINT32_T
#endif
#ifndef  MPI_UINT_LEAST64_T
# define MPI_UINT_LEAST64_T  MPI_UINT64_T
#endif
#ifndef  MPI_INT_FAST8_T
# define MPI_INT_FAST8_T  MPI_INT8_T
#endif
#ifndef  MPI_INT_FAST16_T
# define MPI_INT_FAST16_T  MPI_INT64_T
#endif
#ifndef  MPI_INT_FAST32_T
# define MPI_INT_FAST32_T  MPI_INT64_T
#endif
#ifndef  MPI_INT_FAST64_T
# define MPI_INT_FAST64_T  MPI_INT64_T
#endif
#ifndef  MPI_UINT_FAST8_T
# define MPI_UINT_FAST8_T  MPI_UINT8_T
#endif
#ifndef  MPI_UINT_FAST16_T
# define MPI_UINT_FAST16_T  MPI_UINT64_T
#endif
#ifndef  MPI_UINT_FAST32_T
# define MPI_UINT_FAST32_T  MPI_UINT64_T
#endif
#ifndef  MPI_UINT_FAST64_T
# define MPI_UINT_FAST64_T  MPI_UINT64_T
#endif
```

If you use a Makefile to organize your product, I would use something like

```
CC      := mpicc
CFLAGS  := -Wall -O2
LDFLAGS := -lmpi

all: your-main-program

clean:
    @rm -f *.o extra_mpi_types_internal.h

type-generator: type-generator.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

extra_mpi_types_internal.h: type-generator
    ./type-generator > $@

%.o: %.c extra_mpi_types_internal.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@

your-main-program: all.o needed.o object.o files.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

although this approach does mean that you cannot cross-compile MPI programs for a different architecture.

---

Alternatively, you can use [pre-defined compiler macros](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/) to determine the OS, hardware architecture, and C library used, to include a pre-prepared header file with the correct macro definitions:

```c
/* extra_mpi_types.h */
#ifndef   EXTRA_MPI_TYPES_H

#if defined(__linux__)
#if   defined(__amd64__)
#include <extra-linux-amd64.h>
#elif defined(__i386__)
#include <extra-linux-x86.h>
#elif defined(__aarch64__)
#include <extra-linux-arm64.h>
#elif defined(__ARM_ARCH_4T__)
#include <extra-linux-arm-4t.h>
#else
#error "Unsupported Linux hardware architecture"
#endif

#elif defined(_WIN64)
#include <extra-win64.h>

#elif defined(_WIN32)
#include <extra-win32.h>

#else
#error  Unsupported operating system.
#endif

#endif /* EXTRA_MPI_TYPES_H */
```

The contents for each of the above files (or rather, the architectures and operating systems *as needed*), can be either discovered using a C program like above, or by examining the C compiler and library header files.

Comment: *All existing C implementations supporting <stdint.h> types typedef the minimum-width and fastest minimum-width integer types to types compatible with the exact-width types.*  And that means going through the trouble of using the minimum-width or the fastest minimum-width integer types is entirely pointless **because** you wind up using the standard types anyway.  The only time you can use the minimum-width or fastest minimum-width integer types is when they do map to the standard types.  **So just use the standard types**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That's your opinion, so why don't you write it as an answer?  I didn't want to write a "Don't do that" answer.  Personally, I use the exact-width types because they have exactly defined ranges on all architectures, and minimum-width fast types for local variables in code (but never for storage or communications).  I rarely use short, or int for anything, because I write HPC code that runs as-is on both ILP32 and LP64 architectures (ARM and x86-64 on Linux); in Linux `long` (and not int) is the "native" integer type.